# A do nothing line in a bash script

Tags: bash

I have a bash script and I have an `else` statement which I want it to do nothing.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The standard way to do it is using [colon `:`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_16):

```
if condition; do
  command
else
  :
fi
```

or [`true`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/true.html#tag_20_133):

```
if condition; do
  command
else
  true
fi
```

But why not just skipping the `else` part:

```
if condition; do
  command
fi
```

---

In `zsh` and `yash`, you can even make the `else` part empty:

```
if condition; then
  command
else
fi
```

Answer (score 7):

The `else` statement is optional. Just type:

```
if [ expr ]; then
#bla
#bla
#bla
fi
```