# Is there something similar or like "pass" in python in bash/shell programming?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, python, programming

I sometimes need a command like [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement) in Python in my bash scripts.

**Like:**

```
if grep something
then
    pass
else
    code
fi
```

**In Python you have:**

```
>>> for element in a:
...     if not element:
...         pass
...     print element
```

**QUESTION:**

*I always use `continue` but it gives an error that it should only be used in a `for`, `while` or `until` loop.*

What would you do in this circumstance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your title is fully answered by [A do nothing line in a bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/287866/86440): `:` or `true` are effectively equivalent to `pass`.

However in these circumstances I would flip the condition:

```
if ! grep something
then
    code
fi
```

and

```
>>> for element in a:
...     if element:
...         print element
```

Comment: Also, `grep -q`, depending on whether the script is supposed to output the matches or not.

Comment: Better IMO is `grep something || { code; }`, using `||` for when a command fails rather than an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

That's a ugly kludge, but if you really want to do that you could use

```
usleep
```

This command pauses the execution for 1 microsecond.

You could use it in a function:

```
function do_nothing {
   usleep
}
```

and then use the function like Python's `pass`.

It works but is not very nice to read and would break the logic flow of the script, so I don't recommend to use it. A much better solution is to rewrite the script instead as @StephenKitt suggested.